# password_verify() returning false

Tags: php, magento, passwords, magento-1.7, php-password-hash

I'm having a seeming spontaneous problem. Suddenly my `password_verify()` function is returning false.

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql1 =
    "SELECT `merchants_id`, `password`, `name` FROM table_name WHERE `email` = :email;";
$binds = array(
    'email' => $email
);

$findvalue = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($sql1, $binds);
$findvalue = $findvalue[0];

$verified = password_verify($password, $findvalue['password']);
?>
```

As you may be able to see, I'm using Magento (Fully patched 1.7) and their methods to execute the query.

If I parse it through `password_get_info($findvalue['password'])` it picks up that the password is valid and outputs the expected data (encryption type etc) however `$verified` returns `FALSE`

The database field is set, and has always been set, to `varchar(255)`.

**EDIT---**

This is the code that was used to create the passwords:

```
    $hash = password_hash($value['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $updateSql = 'UPDATE table_name SET `password` = :password WHERE `merchants_id` = :merchant_id;';
    $updateBinds = array(
        'password' => $hash,
        'merchant_id' => $value['merchants_id']
    );
    $cxn->query($updateSql, $updateBinds);
```

Also, as requested here is a password string: `$2y$10$TfTULzD9eVUEdjaquhcUmOhGD07X5VV3MloCpjaOmpt3GqOBpEhmm`

Comment: Your code seems fine - can you give example input values that fail?

Comment: I've tried with 2 different users logins so it's not distinct to a local user.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood. have updated the question @1615903

Comment: And what is the actual password that should verify against that hash?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is, write a small script that checks the validity: `password_verify("mypassword", '$2y$10$TfTULzD9eVUEdjaquhcUmOhGD07X5VV3MloCpjaOmpt3GqOBpEhmm');` - if it succeeds, one of your input values is wrong in the actual code. If it fails, the hash is not generated from that password.

Comment: I reset the password but I'd love to know what made *all* my passwords suddenly not work. I recently found out that we upgraded PHP to 5.6. I wonder if this could have been the issue.

Comment: BCrypt hashes are not platform dependent, so that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset my password and it all worked.

I have a suspicion that it may be because I upgraded my PHP version to 5.6 meaning the algorithm may have changed.